# Is it correct to write "feast luxurious" instead of "feast luxuriously"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs, predicate-adjectives

> And much there is on which my ear and eye
> Can feast luxurious.

The preceding sentence is a line from a [sonnet](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=STzwAgAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA20&dq=%22And%20much%20there%20is%20on%20which%20my%20ear%20and%20eye%20Can%20feast%20luxurious.%22&hl=en&source=newbks_fb&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22And%20much%20there%20is%20on%20which%20my%20ear%20and%20eye%20Can%20feast%20luxurious.%22&f=false) by [Michael Madhusudan Dutt](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Madhusudan_Dutt) (1824–1873).

Is it correct to write "feast luxurious" instead of "feast luxuriously"? Why? Why not?

Comment: In poetry, it’s writer’s discretion.

Comment: It's an echo of an 18th century adverbial use of luxurious:. Cf: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Odyssey_of_Homer_Translated_by_Alexa/bjeUWVECgFwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22feast+luxurious%22&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover